# How to insert data in 2 tables at a same time in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one form from where i am inserting data in one table.now i want to add my data in another table too how can i achieved this in code igniter.my second table is `fin_tran`
Controller :

```
public function insert_uk_slip()
    {               

        $employee_name = $this->input->post('employee_name');     
        $net_pay = $this->input->post('net_pay');
        $userInfo = array('emp_id'=>$employee_name,           
            'net_pay'=>$net_pay,  
            );            
        $this->load->model('Pay_slips_model');
        $result = $this->Pay_slips_model->insert_uk_slip($userInfo);            
        if($result > 0)
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'New User created successfully');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User creation failed');
        }            
        redirect('responsible/upload_uk_slip');        
    }
```

model:

```
public function insert_uk_slip($userInfo)
    {
        $this->db->trans_start();
        $this->db->insert('uk_new_salary_slip', $userInfo);            
        $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();            
        $this->db->trans_complete();            
        return $insert_id;
    }
```

Comment: Just do another `$this->db->insert('the-other-table', $userInfo)`?

Comment: However, if you need to store the same data again in different tables, it feels like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to have a batch query that will add data on 2 tables  otherwise none of them will have the data. If that so, Try to use

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('AN SQL QUERY...');
$this->db->query('ANOTHER QUERY...');
$this->db->query('AND YET ANOTHER QUERY...');

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
        $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

please read:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/transactions.html

that will allow you to commit or rollback queries .